# Python webapp IndexError raised by FastCGI-stderr from lighttpd on remote server; executes ok locally

Tags: python, fastcgi

I have setup a lighttpd remote server that I want to run a python application using fastcgi. The application has a login with a backdoor. When I try to use it,  I get an internal server error. In the lighttpd error log, I see:

```
2020-01-23 20:05:51: (mod_fastcgi.c.2702) FastCGI-stderr:     paswd = getEntry("students","password","username",user)

2020-01-23 20:05:51: (mod_fastcgi.c.2702) FastCGI-stderr:   File "/root/web-crs/control.py", line 35, in getEntry

2020-01-23 20:05:51: (mod_fastcgi.c.2702) FastCGI-stderr:     return bob[0][col]

2020-01-23 20:05:51: (mod_fastcgi.c.2702) FastCGI-stderr:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/db.py", line 531, in __getitem__

2020-01-23 20:05:51: (mod_fastcgi.c.2702) FastCGI-stderr:     raise IndexError(str(i))

2020-01-23 20:05:51: (mod_fastcgi.c.2702) FastCGI-stderr: IndexError: 0
```

When I run the application locally on my machine, I'm able to login through the backdoor fine.

This is the code in control.py that seems to be causing the IndexError:

```
def getEntry(table,col,key,ID):
"""
returns value of column from corresponding key/ID. Returns
only one entry.
"""
wherestring = "{0}=\"{1}\"".format(key,ID)
bob = ctrl.select(table,where=wherestring,what=col)
if bool(bob): #Calling bool(bob) depletes the iterator  
    bob = ctrl.select(table,where=wherestring,what=col)
    return bob[0][col]
else:
    return None
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated, my experience in this area is limited. Thanks!

Comment: The data in 'bob' in `return bob[0][col]` does not appear to be valid.

Comment: re: gstrauss, is it evident from here what's invalid about the data in 'bob'? If not, how to check? Also, I'm using the same database files on the server as locally, so is there a likely reason this would work locally but not via fastcgi? Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to answer those questions yourself.  The problem is clearly in your python code, as the python code is throwing an exception.  `bob` is likely null.